# Date.yesterday not finding any results

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've looked around and can't see any reason why my Date.yesterday query isn't working.

I have this in my model:

```
  scope :yesterday, lambda {
    where('acctstarttime = ?', Time.now - 1.day)
  }
```

And I've tried

```
 scope :yesterday, lambda {
   where('acctstarttime = ?', (Time.now - 1.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
 }
```

And...

```
scope :yesterday, lambda {
   where('acctstarttime = ?', Date.yesterday)
 }
```

I get a result like this:

```
 Radacct.yesterday.count
 (440.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `radacct` WHERE (acctstarttime like '2013-01-27 22:55:31')
```

(I've also tried Date.yesterday)

Where as using today yields:

```
 Radacct.today.count
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `radacct` WHERE (acctstarttime >= '2013-01-28')
 => 16,456
```

If I modify the look up as follows it works:

```
 Radacct.find(:all, :conditions => ["acctstarttime like ?", (Date.today-1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+ "%"]).count
```

Am I just tired or is this overly complicated? What's the best and shortest way in Rails 3 to achieve this? It seems to get stuck with the time aspect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the '>=' on `today`. The problem is that you are testing equality with yesterday, when what you really want to test is a range. Try this:

```
scope :yesterday, lambda {
  where(:acctstarttime => Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day..Date.yesterday.end_of_day)
}
```

Or

```
scope :yesterday, lambda {
  where('acctstarttime >= ? && acctstarttime <= ?', Date.yesterday, Date.today)
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm not going nuts. It's just wrong what I was doing. Thanks daniel. A quick but accurate answer. S